# Are there any stats for the NX-class starship?

Tags: vehicles, star-trek-adventures

Are there any stats for the NX-class ship? And if so, where?

After looking, I didn't find any, but I am sure I've seen them printed somewhere before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Stats for the *NX*-class ship are in the *Command Division* book.

The *Command Division* sourcebook for *Star Trek Adventures* is available in [PDF format on DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/243139/Star-Trek-Adventures-Command-Division-supplement), as well as on Modiphius Entertainment's website in [PDF](https://www.modiphius.net/products/star-trek-adventures-command-division-supplement-pdf) and [hardcover](https://www.modiphius.net/products/star-trek-adventures-command-division-supplemental-rulebook) formats. The product description mentions that the *NX* is included:

> The Command Division supplement PDF includes:
>
> - [...]
> - Over a dozen additional starships and support craft to command and
>   pilot, **including the *NX***, *Nebula*, *Sovereign*, and *Steamrunner*
>   classes, as well as many shuttle types and the indomitable Work Bee!

According to [this Reddit post by /u/Takeshi_Yamato on /r/StarTrekAdventures](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrekadventures/comments/adbimu/ship_building_thought_exercise_19_nx/), the stats for the *NX*-class ship can be found on p. 54 of the *Command Division* sourcebook. I don't own the book, so I can't confirm this page number myself.

(There also exist homebrew versions of the ship, including [one credited to /u/AdmiralTrek](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrekadventures/comments/adbimu/ship_building_thought_exercise_19_nx/edfgvdi/) in the comments of the Reddit post linked above, and [one by "Jester" David Gibson on the Continuing Mission fan site](https://continuingmissionsta.com/2017/11/05/starship-sunday-nx/).)

Comment: Note: I actually did get the *Star Trek Adventures* books from a recent Humble Bundle, so I will actually be able to confirm this once I take a look through those PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

As of August 2020 there is now an official set of stats for the *U.S.S. Enterprise* NX-01, rather than the NX class in general, in the *Star Trek Adventures: Enterprise Player Characters* PDF, available from the [Modiphius](https://www.modiphius.net/products/star-trek-adventures-enterprise-player-characters) website or [DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/320453/Star-Trek-Adventures-Enterprise-Player-Characters).

Note that [there have been corrections to other parts of the book](https://forums.modiphius.com/t/the-nx01-crew-pdf/12560/8), so if you acquired the PDF earlier, you may need to update.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.